# How to properly un-nest a jquery javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, strict

I need to un-nest the following code because strict javascript is throwing errors in Safari and Firefox (it works in Chrome for some reason) that say functions may only be declared at the top level or immediately within another function and that $ is not a function. So I figured I needed to split up the function declarations. The code is supposed to loop through all elements in a form that are required and prevent submission if all required fields are not used.

Other Notes: I'm developing in Google Apps Script, which requires strict javascript. Also note that the '#submitbutton' is actually a regular button that calls a google.script which handles submission.

Original Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submitbutton').on('click', function() {
   $(this).val("Submitting...");
   //check for required fields
   var emptyFields = $('[required]').filter(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("warning");
       if ($(this).val().length === 0){
         $(this).addClass("warning")
         return true
       } else {
         return false
       }
   });

   if (emptyFields.length === 0) {
       $(this).prop('disabled', true);
       document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('bePatient').style.display = 'inline';
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
    } else{
      $(this).val("Submit Application")
      document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'inline';
      document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.color = 'red';
    }
});
</script>
```

I tried breaking it into the code below, but now it isn't even working in Chrome. Did I do something wrong?

```
<script type="text/javscript">

$('#submitbutton').on('click', validatefunction('#submitbutton'));

function validatefunction(this) {
   $(this).val("Submitting...");
   //check for required fields
   var emptyFields = $('[required]').filter(filterfunction(index));

   if (emptyFields.length === 0) {
       $(this).prop('disabled', true);
       document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById('bePatient').style.display = 'inline';
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
    } else{
      $(this).val("Submit Application");
      document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.display = 'inline';
      document.getElementById('incompleteWarning').style.color = 'red';
    }
};

function filterfunction(this){
       $(this).removeClass("warning");
       if ($(this).val().length === 0){
         $(this).addClass("warning");
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
};

</script>
```

Comment: the `this` reference is not binded correctly, and you are passing `this` as an argument, i suggest first changing this to a concrete variable name. You could try `var self = $(this);` and pass that to that function, or use `bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will call your function with the previously expected context. This means you only need to do:

```
$('[required]').filter(filterfunction);
```

and

```
$('#submitbutton').on('click', validatefunction);
```

Comment: Great. This fixed my code in Chrome [Note that I also removed the arguments in the function declarations]. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my original two errors that I've been getting in Safari and Firefox...

Comment: You can try replacing `document.getElementById('someID')` with `$('#someID')`. I'd look at replacing some of your other vanilla javascript with jQuery equivalents as jQuery will handle most browser compatibility for you.

Comment: Make sure you're including jQuery with the proper script tag. If you're trying in IE8, make sure you're not using jQuery v2. What errors are you getting?

Comment: At top of HTML before other scripts: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Errors in Firefox: `Uncaught in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function` and 
`Uncaught TypeError: $ is undefined`.  Similar errors occur in Safari. It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: I think it has to do with the Google HTML service restraints: [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions). I'm developing in Google Apps Script so I'm restricted to using one of their three modes: IFRAME, NATIVE, or EMULATED. I currently use NATIVE. If I switch to IFRAME or EMULATED, then the code doesn't even work in Chrome.